# Does eclipse support xml comment description like Visual Studio?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, xml-comments

I'm trying to switch a project from Visual Studio to Eclipse. In Visual Studio you could comment functions and parameters with xml comments. These comments where then shown in the code completion.

```
/// <summary>
/// The function HotKey.DeInstallKey() deinstalls a single HotKey. The function uses an ASCII character to identify the key that has to be deinstalled. The function works for local and for global HotKeys.
/// </summary>
/// @cond VISUAL_PARAM
/// <param name="Key">The HotKeyTag.</param>
/// @endcond
/// @param[in] Key The HotKeyTag.
void DeInstallKey(int Key);
```

Does Eclipse support that as well, or how do I have to change the comments to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention: C / C++